# How to programmatically control cogonito user access S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

**Background**

I use S3 to store paid content. My app also uses Cognito to authenticate users and also tracks who purchased what content. But how can I make an S3 object only accessible to the paid users?

For example: the object at "mybucket/private-content/obj1.pdf" needs to be accessible to user A but not to user B depending on the purchase record.

I can think of two solutions for now but none of them are ideal.

**Solution 1**

Make the bucket private. Then generate a signed URL for an object after the user purchased the content.
**Problem**: User A can purchase the content and share the signed URL to user B. User B can access the object without paying.

**Solution 2**
Every time when a user purchased some content, copy the object to a user folder in S3. And use a bucket policy to limit the user only accessing his own folder.
**Problem**: Need to duplicate content over and over. This increases my storage cost.

Comment: When User A wants to share content, he can download then send via private message. You can not restrict it. But you can have a function to generate URL and limit the expired time

Answer (score 0):

Found a good enough solution using CloudFront signed URL together with a custom policy. In the custom policy, you can specify an IP range/address that can access the protected content. 
This means that if a user share the link to another user, most likely the link will not work for the other user.

[See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-overview.html)